# Spring Integration 4.1 Orderly Shutdown using stopActiveComponents no longer closes context after wait time

Tags: spring-integration

Prior to Spring Integration 4.1, using the control bus to issue and orderly shutdown with for example a 20 second delay, using `stopActiveComponents` would've resulted in the application context being closed and the PID ending.

When upgrading to Spring Integration 4.1, issuing the same control bus command now leaves the context still loaded and the PID running.

Looking at the Spring Integration 4.1 documentation it does look as though that this might be the new behaviour.

Does anyone know if there is a way of getting the previous behaviour back so that the context itself is again eventually closed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like we wasn't right when we removed the `stopNonSpringExecutors()` (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3455).

Can you be sure that you don't use any `Executor` which isn't Spring's `TaskExecutor` ?

And feel free to raise a JIRA issue on the matter. But you have to provide some short sample to allow us to reproduce this regressing and fix it.

Thank you very much for catching it!

Comment: Just to be clear "`using stopActiveComponents would've resulted in the application context being closed and the PID ending.`" - the `stopActiveComponents` did not "close" the context; but yes, leaving the executor(s) running can hold up the context from exiting; as a work-around, you could issue a context.destroy() after `stopActiveCompnents` which should destroy the executors.